# Марлен Берг -- в родительном падеже? Ассоль Белкания -- в предложном?

Tags: падежи

Марлен Берг -- в родительном падеже?
Ассоль Белкания -- в предложном?

Answer (score 1):

Для Марлен Берг - женское имя/фамилия на твердый согласный  не склоняются.

Об Ассоли  (Ассоль) Белкания - имя может склоняться по образцу сущ. 3-го скл.

Answer (score 0):

Это имена собственные, как я понимаю, женского рода.

Поэтому первое не изменяется по падежам (нет Марлен Берг), второе по правилам должно склоняться (об Ассоли Белкании), но очень часто встречаются рекомендации подобные фамилии не склонять.